# How should I choose a VoIP provider?

Tags: voip

Suppose you want to select a VoIP provider that would make possible for you to make calls from your computer to regular phones. Where would you look for names, and what sources or criteria would you use to evaluate their reliability? In short, how would you go about making a list of candidate providers and then selecting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top Ten Reviews has a pretty good list of VOIP provider that they think is the best

http://voip-service-review.toptenreviews.com/

But here's what I look for in a VOIP provider:

Cost (per month/per minute), features, connection time, Enhanced 911 Service, distance between their server and your phone.

Answer (score 0):

also depending on your needs, providers support various options:

- do you need a 800 number?
- do you need a number in a specific area?
- do you need numbers in other countries?
- do you need to call Skype users or receive calls from Skype users?
- do you need an iNUM number?